# MediaController of videoview implemented in DialogFragment not updating correctly

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

MediaController of videoview works as intended when implemented in an Activity. But as per my application requirement when I implemented the same in DialogFragment. The MediaController goes behind the videoview. I could solve this issues by using a framelayout and with the help of the following code:

```
((ViewGroup) mediaController.getParent()).removeView(mediaController);
((FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoViewWrapper)).addView(mediaController);
```

The above code brings the Media-controls to the foreground. But the seek-bar updates incorrectly. It gets stuck at certain position. Only if the user touches the screen/symbols it gets updated correctly.

How can I make it update correctly in DialogFragment? In the same way as it used to work in Activity(creating a custom media control component would be the last option).

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Would Like to see your code in details?

Comment: @BhavdipSagar what would you like to know ? If you can specify I can edit and add only the required.

Answer (score 1):

I also had seek-bar updating problem when MediaController was in FrameLayout.So I delete the FrameLayout and the problem with horizontally centering was solved in this way. Hope this will  help someone save time.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    Window window = getWindow();
    layoutParams.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
    layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    window.setAttributes(layoutParams);
```